# Old URL Redirect website after migration

Tags: urls, migration

I have migrated my old website from example1.wordpressstaging.com to epxample2.com on a new server (using All-in-one Migration Plugin). Everything went fine with the migration. Now after I complete the migration an search for http:// example2.com I reach the correct domain, but when I search for https://.com I get redirected to my old example1.wordpressstaging.com URL. I already check in phpMyAdmin and within wp-option the siteurl and home is on mysite.com (and not the staging one).

Does anyone know how I can fix this https:// redirection issue so that I end on https://example2.com instead of the old https://example1.wordpressstaging.com ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use htaccess on the old place to redirect to the new place?  And make sure that the new place has SSL (another htaccess directive).

Much googles/bings/ducks on how to use htaccess to redirect from old domain to new one.